# Is $f$ integrable with countably infinite discontinuities $?$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

**Question**

$$S=\{1/n ;n\in \mathbb N\}$$ . $$f:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb R$$ be  defined  as  $$f(x)=\{^{1;x\in S} _{0 ; otherwise} $$

Is $f$  integrable  $?$

And  what  happens  if  $$f=\{^{x;x\in S}_{0;otherwise} $$  $?$

**My Attempt**

For the  first  case say  $$P=\{x_0,x_1,.....,x_n\}$$  be  any  arbitrary  partition with  $x_0=0$

So  $sup_{[x_0,x_1]} f(x)=1$ and  for  the  other  segments ,  depending  on  whether  they  have  a  ${1/n}$  or  not ; $sup_{[x_{k-1},x_k]}f(x)=1\ \ or\ \ 0$

Hence , $U(P,f)=1+k;k\le n$  And $L(P,f)=0$  always. So  $$U(P,f)-L(P,f)=1+k$$

Where  is  it  going  when  limit of  $n$  is  taken  to  $\infty$  $?$ .

For  the  second  case , $$U(P,f)-L(P,f)=1+\Sigma_{i=1}^{n} \{1/n\}$$

In  both  cases ,  taking  $n\rightarrow \infty$  the  *difference*  $U(P,f)-L(P,f)$  diverges  so  none  of  these  $f$'s  are  integrable .

*What  are  the mistakes  that  I have  made $?$ And  how  do I get  the  results  correct $?$*

Thanks.

Comment: To get the correct upper/lower sums, you have to multiply the upper/lower estimate in each interval of the partition by the *length* of that interval.

Answer (score 1):

Both $f$ are Riemann integrable, with a proof below for the first one.

For $N \ge 1$ integer, define $$s_N(x)=\begin{cases} 0 & \text{ for } x \in [0, \frac{1}{N+1})\\
f(x) & \text{ else} \end{cases} \ \ \ 
S_N(x)=\begin{cases} 1 & \text{ for } x \in [0, \frac{1}{N+1})\\
f(x) & \text{ else} \end{cases}$$
$s_N,S_N$ are step functions and for $x \in [0,1]$: $$s_N(x) \le f(x) \le S_N(x).$$ Moreover $$0 \le \int_0^1 (S_N(x)-s_N(x)) dx = \frac{1}{N+1} \to 0$$ as $N \to +\infty$, proving that $f$ is Riemann integrable.